# Python - merge items of a dynamic nested list in a single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a code which takes input of the users and creates a nested list.

```py
List = [list 1, list2, list 3,.....]
```

The list 1, list 2, list 3 and so on are dynamic and can keep increasing or decreasing.

So far my code output is:

```py
All_data = [[a,b],[c,d],[1,2],[3,4],.....]
```

The output that I want (for the dynamic nested list):

```py
All_data = [a,b,c,d,1,2,3,4,......]
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution to solve this?

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
itertools.chain(*All_data)
```

Or:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(All_data)
```

This creates an iterator, if you want to get a list:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(All_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.concatenate()`. It will condense the nested list into a single list.

If your nested list is dynamic and can grow exponentially, then I will suggest to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` from itertools library. It will be faster because it will not convert the list into a numpy array like the first option.